# Git integration for midnight commander or alternatives

Tags: ubuntu, file-management, midnight-commander

Does Midnight Commander offer support for Git like highlighting changed / added files or is there an alternative File Manager supporting this?

Update:

Something similar to WebStorm/IntelliJ integration in Project View would be enough:

[image]

Red is new, green is changed, white is unchanged.

Comment: As said: highlight (by different colors) new / changed files in a directory under Git version control would be good enough

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Midnight Commander [doesn't seem to support plugins](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288456/are-there-midnight-commander-plugins). Doesn't look like you expect a Windows solution?

Comment: No, I'm looking for a Ubuntu/macOS solution.